# Using insertionSort to sort a vector of pointers to class Objects? (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, insertion-sort

I'm working on a program in which I need to sort a vector of pointers to objects. I would like to use insertionSort() as I've used this in the past, but I'm not entirely sure how to make it work for pointers, but furthermore, Vertex class objects.

Is this even possible, though?

Here is my Vertex class:

```
#include "Edge.h"
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Vertex
{
    private:
        int vertexNum; //number of the vertex for identification purposes
        int degree;
        bool known;
        vector<Edge> adjacentVertices; //vector of vertices that are adjacent to the vertex we are currently looking at
        int dv; //distance 
        int pv; //previous vertex
        Vertex *vertex;
    public:
        Vertex()
        {
            dv = INT_MAX;
            known = false;
        }

        void setKnown(bool Known)
        {
            known = Known;
        }

        bool getKnown()
        {
            return known;
        }

        void setVertexNum(int VertexNum)
        {
            vertexNum = VertexNum;
        }

        void setDegree(int Degree)
        {
            degree = Degree;
        }

        vector<Edge> & getAdjacentVertices()
        {
            return adjacentVertices;
        }

        int getVertexNum()
        {
            return vertexNum;
        }

        int getDegree()
        {
            return degree;
        }

        int getDV() const 
        {
            return dv;
        }

        void setAdjacentVertex(int AdjacentVertex, int Weight)
        {
            Edge newEdge;
            newEdge.setWeight(Weight);
            newEdge.setAdjVertex(AdjacentVertex);
            adjacentVertices.push_back(newEdge);
        }

        friend ostream & operator <<(ostream & outstream, Vertex *vertex)
        {
            outstream << vertex->getVertexNum() << endl;
            outstream << vertex->getDegree() << endl;
            outstream << vertex->getKnown() << endl;
            vector<Edge> E = vertex->getAdjacentVertices();
            for(int x=0;x<E.size();x++)
            {
                outstream << E[x].getAdjVertex() << endl;
                outstream << E[x].getWeight() << endl;
            }
            return outstream;
        }

        friend bool operator < (const Vertex & v1, const Vertex & v2);

};
```

And here are the contents of my vector which I am trying to sort:

```
2
2  2
4  1
2
4  3
5  10
2
1  4
6  5
4
3  2
5  2
6  8
7  4
1
7  6
0
1
6  1
```

Where:

```
2 is the number of edges 
2 is the adjacent vertex 
2 is the weight
4 is the adjacent vertex
1 is the weight

2 is the number of edges
4 is the adjacent vertex
3 is the weight
5 is the adjacent vertex
10 is the weight
```

...etc

Comment: why you putting Vertex* in the class? You mentioned about using vector, but it looks like you are using a linked list.

Comment: You can use `std::sort` with a lambda comparator that tells it how you want to "sort" pointers. If you don't want to do that, define your insertion sort as a template that takes in a comparator and use the comparator when comparing things. Otherwise, sorting pointers makes no sense.

Comment: What's your implementation for "friend bool operator <"?